# What is the perfect way to paginate realtime data with cursor based pagination?

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination, paginator, laravel-pagination

I have a large set of realtime messages data which loads based on the order of its rating.

For the temporary solution, I am using is skip-n-limit method pagination.

I know I can handle this using the cursor-based pagination as FB or twitter API does. But my problem here is I am ordering messages based on the message rating.

Reference: in https://www.sitepoint.com/paginating-real-time-data-cursor-based-pagination/

If it was ordered-by-id I can check this with `max_id` & `min_id`

Any suggestion or ideas are welcome